# PowerCLI equivalent to "chkconfig usbarbitrator off"

Tags: powershell, powercli

what is the PowerCLI equivalent to CLI command:

**chkconfig usbarbitrator off**

I would like to execute it from PowerShell

Comment: Just type the command and press `Enter`. (PowerShell is a shell, after all. It can run commands you type.)

Answer (score 0):

[Invoke-VMScript](https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.powercli.cmdletref.doc%2FInvoke-VMScript.html) can run shell commands on Linux guest vms with vmtools.

To run arbitrary shell commands on ESXi hosts from PowerCLI without SSH, you might try the [esxcli-shell](https://www.v-front.de/2013/01/release-esxcli-plugin-to-run-arbitrary.html) package.

Comment: the esxcli-shell package would need to get installed on the host first (not desired)
still looking for direct PowerCLI equivalent, if one exists
thank you for the follow-up anyway

Comment: Does not exist, afaik. Why not use SSH?

Comment: the simplest workaround, at least for me, was to use plink.exe utility from putty - e.g.

plink.exe -pw "password" "root@VMHostName" "chkconfig usbarbitrator off"

SSH needs to be enabled on the host though.

I wish all admin tasks were available from PowerCLI